# Specific blog ideas

Tags: discussion

List specific blog article ideas that the community has.  One idea per answer.   List specific ideas that you think you would like to see either as a reoccurring theme or a particular topic you would like to see more information about via the blog.

Answer (score 12):

We could have a series of posts authored by the winners of the weekly featured image contests. The creator of the image would do a short post explaining what inspired the shot and/or how s/he achieved the effect in the photo. It's easy, it's relevant to the site, and there will always be material for it. (This would, of course, require that the weekly featured image winners be willing to do that, but I think it would be a neat series. Even as an occasional thing - once every three or four weeks, since I'm sure not everyone will want to write.)

Comment: Great idea, Laura. Jeez, the guys at Stack Exchange should give you a job! ;)

Answer (score 10):

### Lightroom Tips and Tricks

(alternatively, **Lightroom Fundamentals**)

This would be a series of articles dedicated to teaching readers about the full power and flexibility of Adobe Lightroom. It would start simple and general, and progress through more advanced tools, tips, and techniques.

I am working on an initial draft for the first installment, which would cover in general how to use lightroom to import and manage catalogs of photos, efficiently perform keywording, flagging and tagging, etc.

Comment: This would be great. Being new to Lightroom I've picked and pecked my way to getting a decent workflow down but I'd love to see some other ideas.

Comment: Aye, Lightroom can be tough to use if you don't use it the way it seems to be intended to be used. Plus, it has a lot of less-than-obvious features that can greatly improve ones workflow.

Comment: Guess I should note that there are two articles in the Lightroom Fundamentals column on our blog now. Go have a look, let me know what you think!

Answer (score 4):

What gear did you recently buy.

I'm thinking that a lot of folks here hem and haw about the next lens, camera body, tripod, heck even filter they are going to purchase.  A blog post about what research you did, why you bought, what was the need, what did you compare it to etc. would be interesting.  Seeing others though processes on paper would provide some insight.

Comment: I like this idea. A more "personal" and practical approach to gear reviews, with the buying process involved. Sounds intriguing!

Answer (score 3):

In a similar vein to Jrista's idea, Photoshop tips and tricks, perhaps a beginner's series.

Answer (score 3):

**Home Studio Setup on Budget**

This could be a two post series describing the essential elements one would like to setup in their home studio i.e different lights, umbrellas, stands, backdrops, reflectors and what are the results achievable from the setup. We have a lot of online resources listing the gears one would likely to need, but few of them tells you why you actually need it and sample ways they can be used. A third post could be made discussing the future improvement possibilities in case someone decides to turn it into a full-fledged home studio.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the place for this but an idea for a blog post is a Q and A of a specific person. This would involve a bit of work and get some cooperation with a few people but I would like to see an Interview on the blog with an astronaut about photographing the earth. I was [reading a blog post](http://blogs.nasa.gov/cm/blog/letters.blog/posts/post_1330118334979.html) by Don Pettit (as of this posting on board the ISS) and he spoke of photographing the earth and had this to say:

> Even with a shutter speed of 1/1000th of a second, eight meters (26 feet) of motion occurs during the exposure. Our 400-millimeter telephoto lens has a resolution of less than three meters on the ground. Simply pointing at a target and squeezing the shutter always yields a less-than-perfect image, and precise manual tracking must be done to capture truly sharp pictures. It usually takes a new space station crewmember a month of on-orbit practice to use the full capability of this telephoto lens.

I was amazed at those facts and would love to have a Q/A about how it is done, what his techniques are, etc. Not sure if anything he would say would apply to the photography on earth it is still would be an interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

Android phones for photography. I'm lookin' at @Imre here. :)

[What Android phone has the best camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16346/what-android-phone-has-the-best-camera/16351#16351)

Answer (score 1):

Picking from all the answers, I think that a blog post should be more informative than an answer cause it usually can be longer and the user expects that. In my opinion the blog post is not distracting as different answers to the same question and you are trying to pick the one that looks more correct (although this doesn't happen all the time ofcourse). I believe that the post should be specific and the author should put many details about what he is writing.

Examples

- @Laura's idea is very nice actually. The winner of a week contest can write in details everything about the winning photo. Starting from planning to take the photo to actually taking it and what settings did s/he use and why? What was in his/her mind and what effect s/he was looking for? How did s/he post-process the photo from the beginning till the end? I'm certain that there's a huge opportunity for learning new stuff here.
- @jrista's idea is great! Usually when you watch a lightroom/photoshop tutorial it walks you through a specific feature in the program of how to do something. I would like to see tutorials of how to edit a photo from the beginning since we import it till the end and we export it. Different ideas and artistic views are really important here cause not all people agree on the same thing. But I believe that this will lead to a nice discussion.
- @Thanh's I believe that his idea can be merged with the gear rental that @Laura is running.

At the end I like actually what PhoeoSE is trying to achieve through its blog. I think that the blog will be really helpful and informative. It's a way of gathering all the nice questions in PhotoSE and reformat them into meaningful related articles.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by gear rental program that @Laura's running now, it would be great if Stack Exchange can ask the professional photographers to write articles in the blog about anything they like related to photography.

Answer (score 0):

Also we can pick very nice questions that have more than one answer and write an post about it. For example, my recent [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23003/what-is-ettr-expose-to-the-right) has links to other questions and answers, all of these can be combined into one single post